# Published .Net 7 app not running on ubuntu

Tags: asp.net, systemd, .net-7.0, kestrel-http-server, ubuntu-22.04

I have a .Net 7 solution that contains 2 separate projects.
I am using ubuntu 23.04.

```
/Project1
  - Project1.csproject
  - appsettings.json

/Project2
  - Project2.csproject
  - appsettings.json

MySolution.sln
```

I have ran the command:

```
 dotnet publish 'MySolution.sln' --self-contained false -r linux-x64 -c Release -o publish
 
 MSBuild version 17.4.3+7e646be43 for .NET
 Determining projects to restore...
 All projects are up-to-date for restore.
 Project1 -> /home/myuser/mysolution/project1/bin/Release/net7.0/linux-x64/Project1.dll
 Project1 -> /home/myuser/mysolution/publish/
 Project2 -> /home/myuser/mysolution/project1/bin/Release/net7.0/linux-x64/Project2.dll
 Project2 -> /home/myuser/mysolution/publish/
```

It produces a /publish directory containing the correct code.

Unfortunately, I can not get these apps to run.

My Appsettings files contain Kestrel sections to have each of the projects open on different ports:

Project1/appsettings.json :

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://localhost:5001"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:5001"
    }
  }
}
```

Project2/appsettings.json :

```
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Http": {
      "Url": "http://localhost:5002"
    },
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:5002"
    }
  }
}
```

Even when I navigate directly to the Publish/Project folders and run

```
 dotnet Project1.dll --verbosity=diagnostic
```

I get no output.

My dotnet is installed:

```
.NET SDK:
 Version:   7.0.105
 Commit:    e1bc5e001c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  23.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.23.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.105/

Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  7.0.105 [/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.5 [/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

I have also tried using systemd to boot the project automatically but it starts then deactivates after less than a second.

```
cd /etc/systemd/system/
sudo nano project1.service


[Unit]
Description=Project1

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /home/myuser/mysolution/project1/bin/Release/net7.0/linux-x64/Project1.dll
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-project1
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Any help is appreciated! How do I go about troubleshooting this?
I'm hoping someone can spot a mistake I have made!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my set up was to do with the paths I was using. I moved the published files from the published directory to /var/myapp

```
sudo cp -a /home/myuser/mysolution/ /var/myapp/
```

I then updated the systemd file with these details

```
[Unit]
Description=Project1

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/myapp
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/myapp/project1/Project1.dll
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-project1
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```